# Filter names from Json object/array using jsonpath query

Tags: json, jsonpath, json-query

I am trying to extract all name from computerScience and electronics using json path query

my input json is

```
{
  "computerscience": [
    {
      "name": "john doe",
      "grade": "B",
      "year": "4"
    },
    {
      "name": "Bjarne Stroustrup",
      "grade": "A",
      "year": "4"
    },
    {
      "name": "Dennis Ritchie",
      "grade": "A",
      "year": "4"
    }
  ],
  "someProp1": "false",
  "someProp2": "dirSync",
  "electronics": [
    {
      "name": "thomas edison",
      "grade": "B",
      "year": "4"
    },
    {
      "name": "nichola tesla",
      "grade": "B",
      "year": "4"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to figure out json path which give me below result

```
["john doe", "Bjarne Stroustrup", "Dennis Ritchie" , "thomas edison", "nichola tesla"]
```

I want to extract names from only computerScience and electronics

I am trying few jsonpaths [here](https://jsonpath.com) but it won't work

Comment: Can you also post the few jsonpath that you have tried which won’t work?

Answer (score 3):

This pattern works:

```
$.[computerscience,electronics][*].name
```

This simpler pattern works as long as there aren't any other properties that you want to avoid selecting the names from:

```
$.*[*].name
```

Or if you really just want to collect *all* the names in the document, there's:

```
$..name
```

Comment: And of course I should have mentioned, these operators are documented here: https://github.com/json-path/JSONPath#operators

Comment: As per the  documentation of Jayway JSONpath the query should look like `$.['computerscience','electronics'][*].name` . The names of the properties should be enclosed within single quotes. Try here https://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/